# angular --prod flag gives an error when comparing variable type number with a number

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular 5 app and only when I make the build with --prod flag gives me an error "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types
'string' and 'number'". Here is the code:

```
<div *ngIf="rating >= 0 && rating <= 5">
...
</div>
```

And in the component.ts

```
public rating:number;
```

When I build in develop mode there is no errors and everything works fine, but when i make the build with `ng build --prod` gives me the following error:

> ERROR in src\app\components...component.html(31,25): : Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types
>   'string' and 'number'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like somewhere `rating` is also cast as a string, perhaps implicitly

Comment: And how do I fix that?

Comment: Difficult to say without looking at the whole code. Have a look at your TS file and check if you do anything weird with `rating`, put some breakpoints and verify that it is indeed a number and not a string

Comment: I declare the variable type number, and i retieve the value with an http request, maybe in the process of the request...

Comment: Very much possible

Comment: Ok, later I will debug the whole process to see what is happening in the request, thank you very much